# How to make Visual Studio build the project whenever I press F5?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, settings

On a clean installation of Visual Studio 2010, I loaded my color scheme but now whenever I press F5, my changes are not visible.

How can I make it so that it always builds if the project is changed?

Comment: Which color scheme exactly?  The Visual Studio color scheme?  What would that have to do with building the project?

Comment: Yep, whenever I do this, so settings get screwed, but I swear I did it from scratch many times, always the same result.

Comment: You can at least revert to default settings with Tools / Import and Export Settings / Reset all settings.  No idea why changing the color scheme would affect the build process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your Tool -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run is set to Save all Changes before building.

[image]

Comment: Mine was already set to save all changes, but my second and third dropdown was different so changed those and it works now.

Answer (score 2):

You loaded more options than just the color scheme...  Go change the "build before run" option back the way you want it.

Comment: I know but I did this settings file many times from scratch, next time I will only save the colors, nothing else. Should work better I think.